# Remove object inheritance SQLAlchemy (polymorphic identity)

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

## Problem

Currently we have a system that has several models that inherit from one model (`Quote`) through a polymorphic identity, even though they do not necessarily have a lot in common. This can cause issues and confusion when trying to write code (especially when it comes to objects having similarly named attributes that should not be used).

Our postgresql database setup also reflects this where we have tables inheriting from the quotes table meaning they only define columns that are new for that model. This can make debugging unnecessarily hard and confusing. Especially since only a couple of the columns from the parent are necessary to be inherited.

This has led us to the decision to decouple some of these models from the `Quote` model to improve the flexibility and readability of our code.

---

## Hypothesis

As far as I can think of solutions there is only one. For one of the inheriting models (let's say `Bid`) create a new model that does not inherit from `Quote`. This new `Bid` model (let's say `NewBid` for now) will have all of the required attributes including any ones that were originally inherited from the `Quote` model.
We will then have to replace all usages of `Bid` with `NewBid` and create a migration that copies all data from the `bids` table to the `new_bids` table.

Steps to take would be:

1. Add new model, create migration for new model -> deploy
2. Create data migration copying all information from `bids` to `new_bids`. In this same PR replace all usage of `Bid` with `NewBid` to prevent new data from being entered into the `bids` table. -> deploy
3. Make sure everything works and then remove the `bids` table and `Bid` model (not cascading deletes to references they might have in the DB).
4. Rename the `NewBid` and `new_bids` table to `Bid` and `bids` respectively.

Obviously I would like to avoid running these steps since they feel dangerous and highly susceptible to errors. In case anything goes wrong doing a revert might be hard to accomplish and it may be easy to make a mistake in such a big PR. However, I can't think of another way of accomplishing this.

---

## What have I tried

So far not much has been tried except for a few trivial tries to see if we can easily fix this (i.e. just removing `polymorphic_identity` from the `Quote` and `Bid` models).

Trying to research on how to get rid of this has not proven useful, since most results talk about deletion with polymorphic identities or relations between them. Not how to actually get rid of polymorphic identities all together and just end up with separate tables (without data loss). If I missed that question/answer my apologies.

I could find no answer to this in the docs of SQLAlchemy. Nor could I find anything about this in PostgreSQL docs, which I would not expect since the real problem lies in SQLAlchemy here I think.

---

## Question

How to get rid of inheritance in SQLAlchemy for polymorphic identities, along with inherited tables in postgreSQL, without a loss of data?

---

## Minimal code example

```
class Quote(Base):
    class Type(ValuesMixin):
        QUOTE = "quote"
        BID = "bid"

    __tablename__ = "quotes"
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": "type",
        "polymorphic_identity": Type.QUOTE,
    }

    type = Column(String, nullable=False, default=Type.QUOTE)
    ...


class Bid(Quote):
    __tablename__ = "bids"
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": Quote.Type.BID,
    }
    ...
```

Comment: What is your reasoning for not just altering the subclass table in place?  I guess I'm not sure what the alters would look like, but just dropping the fk constraint and copying the columns over.

Comment: I guess also are you limited to no downtime or can there be downtime during the migration ?